# How to Tune Storage engine of MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have database of just 5 million rows, But inner joins and IN taking to much time (55seconds,60seconds). so i am checking if there is a problem with my MyISAM setting.

**Query:** SHOW STATUS LIKE 'key%'

```
+------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name          | Value       |
+------------------------+-------------+
| Key_blocks_not_flushed | 0           | 
| Key_blocks_unused      | 275029      | 
| Key_blocks_used        | 3316428     | 
| Key_read_requests      | 11459264178 | 
| Key_reads              | 3385967     | 
| Key_write_requests     | 91281692    | 
| Key_writes             | 27930218    | 
+------------------------+-------------+
```

give me your suggestions to increase performance of MyISAM

Comment: MyISAM is a terrible database engine. Use InnoDB If you can, it's got a lot of features MyISAM will never have, like being journaled and not exploding and losing all data if it gets corrupted.

Comment: due to some reasons i cannot change engine, if don't completely now the effect... but we are using a lot of read data... which is best for MyISAM

Comment: MyISAM isn't "best" for anything. It's from the 1990s and hasn't received much attention in over a decade. InnoDB is consistently easier to scale, MySQL 5.0 through 5.7 has made huge improvements in its performance. I'd hope you can change that eventually, you can throw tons of memory at InnoDB's engine and make it fly compared to MyISAM.

Comment: Show us the query, its `EXPLAIN SELECT`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE for the tables.

Comment: `Key_reads/Key_read_requests` is very low; this implies that the "key_buffer" is big enough to efficiently handle MyISAM indexes.  But it does not tell us much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked with more then 45GB database, I was also faced performance issue,

Here are the some stpes which I have taken for improve perfomance.

(1) Remove any unnecessary indexes on the table, paying particular attention to UNIQUE indexes as these disable change buffering. Don't use a UNIQUE index if you have no reason for that constraint; prefer a regular INDEX.

(2)  Inserting in order will result in fewer page splits (which will perform worse on tables not in memory), and the bulk loading is not specifically related to the table size, but it will help reduce redo log pressure.

(3) If bulk loading a fresh table, delay creating any indexes besides the PRIMARY KEY. If you create them once all data is loaded, then InnoDB is able to apply a pre-sort and bulk load process which is both faster and results in typically more compact indexes. This optimization became true in MySQL 5.5.

(4) Make sure to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM. MyISAM can be faster at inserts to the end of a table. Innodb is row level locking and MYISAM is table level locking

(5) Try to avoid complex SELECT queries on MyISAM tables that are updated frequently, and use query like which return less result on first condition

(6) For MyISAM tables that change frequently, try to avoid all variable-length columns (VARCHAR, BLOB, and TEXT). The table uses dynamic row format if it includes even a single variable-length column

Comment: to change from MyISAM to INNO, what commands ands setting i apply please send me commands

Comment: If you want to change table engine please use `ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: For minor issues on the conversion, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb